# Sort numbers inside string

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string that consists of few numbers. First number is the number of the row, remaining are numbers in this row.(Array but string, kind of). The problem is that remaining numbers are unsorted, and I want to find the clearest way of sorting them without creating new List and sorting everything there.

```
String unsorted = '9, 12, 14, 11, 2, 10';
print(unsorted.sort()); // '9, 2, 10, 11, 12, 14'
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why are you not having an `List<Int>` with the numbers instead?

Comment: At this point I can't really imagine any possible way of not using split and creating new list, then sorting it. But I'll leave this here in case if there's some better way.

Comment: @Thor, this is indeed a good question. I have this data stored in Firestore, and this is just a strange preference of mine, not liking to see the document filled with columns of array elements. It's cleaner for me to have one line strings.

Comment: Maybe you can use the CSV package to extract a list of numbers easily, sort, and convert back to CSV. https://pub.dev/packages/csv
of course, you'd need to spereate the fiest number before sorting.

Comment: If you like my idea and want me to write a code example as an answer, just ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant really avoid converting to a list of numbers if you want to sort it.

```
void main() {
  print(sortNumString('9, 12, 14, 11, 2, 10')); // 2, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14
}

String sortNumString(String numString, [String separator = ', ']) =>
    (numString.split(separator).map(int.parse).toList()..sort())
        .join(separator);
```

The `..` means to return the previous thing, the list, since sort returns void.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly experienced when it comes to dart programming language but this is what i came up with.

```
void main() {
     var unsorted = "9, 12, 14, 11, 2, 10";
     var nums_int = unsorted.split(", ").map(int.parse).toList();
     nums_int.sort();
     for (var n in nums_int) {
         stdout.write(n.toString() + ", ");
     }
}
```

That should give the expected output: "2, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14"

Hope this helps.